# DENSE_RANK FAILURE?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Dense rank works **almost** perfectly, (99.9% out of 25,000+ records) but I have found a case in my results where it failed

```
SELECT cns_pid, cns_bid
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cns_pid ORDER BY cns_bid) AS BUILD_NUM
    , cns_sect_num    
FROM real_prop.constrcom
WHERE cns_bid > 0

UNION

SELECT cns_pid, cns_bid
    , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY cns_pid ORDER BY cns_bid) AS BUILD_NUM
    , cns_sect_num    
FROM real_prop.constrres
WHERE cns_bid > 0

ORDER BY cns_pid
```

I need the UNION because some records (cns_pid) have data in both tables (commercial and residential)

Here's a screenshot of my results where DENSE_RANK fails...

[image: RESULTS]

The circled value SHOULD BE a 2, but I have no idea why it's not.
I have a feeling it's because this is one of the few records that has cns_bid data in BOTH tables.
However, I'm not sure.
Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You know now not to use images, because I and others have commented on a number of your previous questions. Many people will downvote and not answer unless you format your data as table markdown.

Comment: And you need to *always* provide a [mre] - to understand your query we need to see you sample starting data, in addition to your query and desired results.

Comment: You are running dense_rank twice, which might explain why you see that because it's in both tables. Modify the query by wrapping the dense_rank around your UNIONed queries.

Comment: @DaleK - how is this not an example of when using an image is actually permissible?
If I'm trying to recreate the error by TYPING data into a table, how does anyone know if the error is REAL or just a typo?  It seems very unintuitive and time intensive to re-type a table just to show a single error.

Comment: Its about making it easier for yourself, by being user friendly for people on all devices, and being easy to read, I can barely see it on my dark backgrounded phone. And there are tools that will let you take your SSMS output and create tabular markdown.

Comment: @Isolated - how do I avoid dense_rank in each table, since the select  has to have the same number of columns from each?

Comment: FYI to you need to use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` - `UNION` is frequently much slower because it de-duplicates at the same time.

Comment: @DaleK - I tried them both and didn't notice any difference in speed.  It returns just under 19,000 records, so it doesn't take long, either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `union` your two selects in a subselect and do `Dense_rank` on the result:

```
SELECT        cns_pid, cns_bid, Dense_rank() OVER (partition BY cns_pid
ORDER BY cns_bid) AS BUILD_NUM, cns_sect_num
FROM
(
    <your first select>
    UNION
    <your second select>
) t
ORDER BY cns_pid
```

Make sure the column names referred in the outer select are properly selected in the subselect queries.

Comment: So, what do i put in the <your first select> and <your second select> parts... the entire SELECT part, each time?

Comment: @TomkatDF2 the two selects that you already union, but you don't need dense-rank in the subselect, instead you can do it on the result in the outer select

Comment: Also, the 2 tables that I'm using UNION for, don't have the same number of fields, so have to pad  SELECTS with "Null as" where necessary

Comment: @TomkatDF2 your outer query needs some fields from the subselect and you only need to select those fields in the subselect, no  need to select via the subselect fields you will not need in the outer select

Comment: - I finally figured it out, thanks!  My ACTUAL select has over 30 columns, so it was a bit of a pain to do the outer select since I have aliases for every field.

Comment: @TomkatDF2 happy to help. If this answer solved your issue, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: @TomkatDF2 You only need to specify aliases for the first `SELECT`

Comment: @Charlieface - Yea, but there are still over 40 of them, and with the way the SELECT gets jammed into one long string (which I hate) it was still a pain to have to type them all and then worry that I didn't miss any.

Comment: @LajosArpad - I actually need all the fields.  I only included the 4 in my question for simplification.